# Selenium - can't find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

This is the page I am trying to scrape: https://directory.brcgs.com/site/10005068

My code:

```
bk_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button [@class='BackButton_backButton__3Czsm']")
bk_btn.click()
```

This is the error I receive:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button [@class='BackButton_backButton__3Czsm']"}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Your locator is correct.
It's quite clear that you are missing a delay.
You need to make the element completely loaded before clicking it.
The preferred way to do that is to use `WebDriverWait` explicit waits as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='BackButton_backButton__3Czsm']"))).click()
```

Comment: If you are going to click an element, you should wait until it's clickable and not just visible to avoid intermittent errors.

Comment: AFAIK element visibility is more mature state than clickability. At least this is what I know. In case this is not a truth - I'll be pleasant if you can show me some kind of documentations supporting this your argument.

Comment: Clickable means it's visible *and* enabled so it's more than just visible. See [the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6ad88d3825f97c67a07a07da944175a586e9ce9c/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L299)

Comment: Are you planning to update your answer to clickable instead of just visible?